# "Create new teams app" causing error Selected user account does not exist in tenant

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams

When you open visual studio code and attempt to create a new teams app by clicking on the option:

[image]

Then you receive the following popup:

[image]

At this point, it loads up the default browser specified under "Default Programs" in your operating system for HTTPS.

You then attempt to sign in to your microsoft account and I receive this error:

[image]

How do I resolve that error?

Comment: Hi @Robert Smith, It will return an error code if you try to use your personal Microsoft account. Try to use with work or school account.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

It will return an error code if you try to use your personal Microsoft account. Try to use with work or school account